# default value in wpf combo box

Tags: wpf, data-binding, combobox

I have a databound combo box that lists Financial Years. The user selects a value from this combo and a value from a 'Client' combo box which then selects that client's report for that financial year for processing by the user.  Although processing a historical document is possible, the default use case is to process a report from the just finished financial year, so I would like to set the Combo box to default to (currently) 2011/2012 which is a string property of the FinancialYear entity.

My xaml:

```
<ComboBox Canvas.Left="353" 
          Canvas.Top="18" 
          Height="23" 
          Name="cboFinancialYear"
          Width="120" 
          DisplayMemberPath="FinancialYear1" 
          ItemsSource="{Binding}" 
SelectedValuePath="FinancialYearID" />;
```

The `Window_Loaded` method in my code behind:

```cs
private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    String thisYear = MainViewModel.GetCurrentFinancialYear();
    lGFinanceEntities = new LGFinanceEntities();
    // Load data into FinancialYears. You can modify this code as needed.
    CollectionViewSource financialYearsViewSource = ((CollectionViewSource)(this.FindResource("financialYearsViewSource")));
    ObjectQuery<FinancialYear> financialYearsQuery = this.GetFinancialYearsQuery(lGFananceEntities);
     financialYearsViewSource.Source = financialYearsQuery.Execute(System.Data.Objects.MergeOption.AppendOnly);
     cboFinancialYear.SelectedItem = thisYear;
}
```

However this doesn't seem to have any effect, and the selected item in the combo box is the first year in the FinancialYear table.

Can anybody point out what I've done wrong?  I've looked around, but most of the default value implementations in combo boxes seem to be of the 'Select a year' sort as instruction text, whereas I want to actually select a default value.

Comment: what type your ItemsSource is?

Comment: @gaurawerma hmmm, interesting. xaml should have a Source attribute in there. I have fixed it to below, but still not working: <ComboBox Canvas.Left="353" Canvas.Top="18" Height="23" Name="cboFinancialYear" Width="120" DisplayMemberPath="FinancialYear1" ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource financialYearsViewSource}}" SelectedValuePath="FinancialYearID" />
 but it still doesn't work

Comment: I meant what is the type of the entity in your ItemsSource

Comment: is a FinancialYear.  In the window resources xaml:
<CollectionViewSource x:Key="financialYearsViewSource" d:DesignSource="{d:DesignInstance model:FinancialYear, CreateList=True}" />

Comment: @eticallogics:
still working on that mvvm thing.  I have code in my xaml code behind at present.  (i'm new)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SelectedItem has a reference to an object of the ItemsSource. You cannot set SelectedItem to a string if your ItemsSource is of `IEnumerable<FinancialYear>` type.

Comment: okies, knew i was doing something wrong.  so, am i correct in thinking (as I commented to ethicallogic) that i need to get an entity and stick it in the SelectedItem, instead of my string?

Comment: yes. But you should not write this logic in your code behind. That breaks the MVVM pattern. Instead you should bind your SelectedItem with a property in your viewmodel.

Comment: yah.  I'm trying to move in that direction but all the tutes I found didn't work.  I figured I'd get it going, then refactor to elegance.  Thanks for your help.  Haven't implemented the solution yet, but gonna mark both as answers, coz they both show me what I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Set

```
cboFinancialYear.SelectedValue=thisYear.FinancialYearID;
```

Use SelectedValue instead of SelectedItem, I hope this will help.

Comment: thanks ethicallogics.  I think this will point me in the right direction.  I should (probably earlier) mention that my GetCurrentFinancialYear method currently only returns the string representation.  If I set that up as a query that returns the entity, then I should be able to compare on that, yeah?